# Facebook app redirects users to my app and becomes unusable once SSO is done

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm updating my app to use the `Facebook SDK(3.1)` and using [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions: allowLoginUI: completionHandler:] for authentication.

Authentication works fine like the following:

1. Open my app and log in, which uses Facebook SSO.
2. Redirected to the Facebook app.
3. Redirected back to my app after authentication, and my app can get
   an access token and

necessary information as expected. -

But I have a problem after authentication.

The problem occurs as follows:

1. Close my app after authentication is done.
2. Open the Facebook app.
3. The Facebook app shows a blank view with the cancel button on the navigation bar -

   - The cancel button does not work.
   - When I scroll down the blank view, the Facebook app redirects to my app.

Here is one way to reproduce the problem:

1. Install my app and log in, which uses Facebook SSO.
2. Log out of my app.
3. Kill the processes of Facebook app and my app running in the background.
4. Open my app and log in again.

I tested it with the latest Facebook app and the previous one both on iOS5 and iOS6,
and was able to reproduce the problem with all combinations.

I want to solve this issue, but don't know where the problem is.
Is it a bug in the Facebook SDK or the Facebook app, or any problem in my app?

Thanks.

Comment: it's like this bug report - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/397758903625713

Comment: any solution for this>'?